# Can't get document.write to display updated variable

Tags: javascript, variables, document.write, input-field

Another rookie-question, which is rooted in a very shallow understanding of JS.

I'm building a small online multistep-form (made in a single html by hiding divs), where every button push is increasing a var with a fixed number:

JS:

```
var score = 20;

function updateScore (){
            score = score + 10;
            result.value = score;
        }
```

I wish to display the score:

Using `<input type="text" name="result" id="result" value="" size="" readonly>` I get the correct value (30).

However when I use `<script>document.write(result)</script>` I get nothing and using `<script>document.write(score)</script>` I get the original var (20).

Same problem when I want the var to output in a jquery progress-bar.

How can I make sure that it is the updated var, which displays in document.write?

EDIT: Complete JS

```
var currentLayer = 'lp';
var score = 10;

function showLayer(lyr){
    hideLayer(currentLayer);
    document.getElementById(lyr).style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById(lyr).style.display = 'block';
    currentLayer = lyr;
}
function hideLayer(lyr){
    document.getElementById(lyr).style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById(lyr).style.display = 'none'
}

function goTo(lyr){
    showLayer(lyr);
    score = score + 10;
    resultat.value = score;
}
function goToMinus(lyr){
    showLayer(lyr);
    score = score - 10;
    resultat.value = score;
}    

  $(function() {
    $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({
      value: score
      });
  });
```

Comment: <script>document.write(document.getElementById("result").value)</script>

Comment: is it possible to show us more code and HTML?  It's not immediately clear to me how exactly you're trying to do things.

Comment: I've added the complete js, if it is any help...

Comment: @MarkWalters Thank you for your suggestion, but nothing displays...

Answer (score 0):

result is a HTML Input Element, so printing the result would be:

```
<script>document.write(result.value)</script>
```

About writting the right "score" var vlaue ensure that there's only one "var score" and it's in the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `document.getElementById('result').value` opposed to `result.value` within your `updateScore` function to ensure your accessing the correct element.

I had included an example where [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) will call your `updateScore` every second to illustrate the result being updated,

```
var score = 20;

function updateScore (){
            score = score + 10;      
            document.getElementById("result").value = score;
        }

setInterval(updateScore,1000);
```

This can be modified at the following fiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/d3QqN/